# What does the CPU Limit mean for App Engine instances?

Tags: google-app-engine, cpu, cpu-usage

I created a site on App Engine and chose the smallest F1 instance class which [according to the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard#instance_classes) has a CPU Limit of 600 MHz.

I limited the app to 1 instance only as a test and let it run several days then checked the CPU utilization on the dashboard. Here's part of the chart:

[image]

As you can see the utilization which is given in Megacycles/sec which I assume equals to one MHz is between like 700 and 1500.

The app uses one F1 instance only, runs without problems, there are no quota errors, but then what does the 600 Mhz CPU limit mean if the utilization is usually above it?

Answer (score 0):

Megacycles/sec is not MHz in this graph. As explained in [Interface QuotaService](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/quota/QuotaService?hl=en#getcputimeinmegacycles):

> Measures the duration that the current request has spent so far
>   processing the request within the App Engine sandbox. Note that time
>   spent in API calls will not be added to this value. The unit the
>   duration is measured is Megacycles. If all instructions were to be
>   executed sequentially on a standard 1.2 GHz 64-bit x86 CPU, 1200
>   megacycles would equate to one second physical time elapsed.

In App Engine Flex, you get an entire CPU core from the machine you are renting out, but in App Engine Standard, it shows the Megacycles since it uses a sandbox.

Note that there is a [feature request in the issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/153050723) on adding CPU% metric under gae_app for App Engine standard and I have relayed your concern about it to the Cloud App Engine product team. However, there is no guarantee of the implementation and ETA at this time. I recommend to star the ticket so that you would receive updates about it.

Comment: Thanks for giving more info, but if I understand you correctly this means the Utilization graph does not tell me how close I am to the instance CPU limit. Is that right? So is there no way for the user to know if one's app is close to the limi and the only way to get notified about this is when the app is actually start failing, because of quota errors? I'm speaking about a scenario when the user sets a max instance number to control costs, so the app can't scale up to a lot of instances.

Comment: Yes it seems to be so at this time. It's a bit complicated but Google basically provide this as a reference to a CPU that provide in their data centers, since they have many processors of different models and types deployed. Seems Google converts these estimates into actual cycles on a processor in their fleet later on, depending on where your application ends up running and what hardware it ends up having access to. So, you may considet it more in terms of "CPU time you get compared to a reference CPU".

Comment: As I mentioend earlier, I have relayed your concern and other customer's feedbacks to the product team. In the meantime, you may take a look at [Cloud Profiler](https://cloud.google.com/profiler/docs) and visualize the CPU usage which is currently a [free service](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing#free-products)

Comment: Thanks for letting the product team know. It would be great if one could see how much of the CPU quota the app actually uses, so one could know when the app is near the limit. Hope to see a stat like that  in the future in additon to Utilization which is not that useful for this purpose.